# how to improve the probability of outputing a correct answer?

Tags: algorithm, random, probability

A sampling algorithm could output any real number in range [0,1],but the correct answer is in the range [0.1,0.2+x]("x" is in range [0,1]), the algorithm can output a correct answer with probability more than "0.8", then how to give a good answer with high probability? (such as run it many times, and pick the median as the right answer)

Comment: output many times without repeats? (no point in printing 0.5 twice..)

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question may be asking about the central limit theorem. If the samplings are independent and identically distributed, the OP could apply the classical form: [Classical CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT)

Otherwise, I recommend viewing the rest of the Wikepedia article to see if any of the other forms are applicable.